# ST_Intersect of polygon(United States) and polyline(hurricane tracks)

Tags: postgresql, spatial

I have two shapefiles in postgresql, a polygon of the United States and a polyline of hurricane tracks. I am attempting to query the name and year of hurricanes that have made landfall in the US on and after 1980? Both shapefiles are of the same projection (SRID 4326, WGS-84).

SELECT DISTINCT s.name, s.year,
FROM storms AS s, states AS us
WHERE ST_Intersects(s.geom, us.geom)
AND s.year >= '1980';

The query completes but does not return any values.

Answer (score 0):

Are table names "storms" and "states" accurate? Do the column names "name," "year," and "geom" exist in table?

It's possible that the storms' geometries don't intersect with the states' geometries, do two simple queries to prove some actually do intersect (no join).

Then clean up query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.name, s.year
FROM storms AS s
JOIN states AS us ON ST_Intersects(s.geom, us.geom)
WHERE s.year >= '1980';
```

removed the extra comma after s.year

explicit join syntax

Comment: To answer your questions: yes, I believe the names to be accurate and the columns do exist in the table. When I bring both shapefiles into ArcPro, I can visually see many hurricane tracks intersecting with the states shapefile.

Comment: When I change my script to look like your the same thing happens. The query completes but returns no values.

Comment: did you run two simple selects with no join to prove there is something that intersects?

Comment: Please provide an example.

Comment: SELECT geom FROM storms; 

SELECT geom FROM states; then just visually look at the data and copy paste some values to prove they really do intersect via ST_Intersects. Purposely add a row to state and a row to storms that have the exact same geom and watch ST_Intersects bring back those as step 1. Then update them to real values and see when ST_Intersects stops working.

Comment: I ran two simple queries where I know a storm intersected a state:

Comment: SELECT FID_1
FROM storms
WHERE FID_1 = 54064;
and

Comment: SELECT NAME
FROM states
WHERE NAME = 'Louisiana';

Comment: each returned the correct answer to the queries.

Comment: SELECT ST_AsText(geom) FROM storms WHERE FID_1 = 54064; SELECT ST_AsText(geom) FROM states WHERE NAME = 'Louisiana'; I want to see the actual geom values.

Comment: "MULTIPOLYGON(((-88.8677 29.861551,-88.865659 29.86262,-88.864312 29.860996999999998,-88.863481 29.858835,-88.862714 29.856783999999998; from here it just keeps going

Comment: perfect, now do something like polygon_text = "MULTIPOLYGON(((-88.8677 29.861551,-88.865659 29.86262,-88.864312 29.860996999999998,-88.863481 29.858835,-88.862714 29.856783999999998)))"

query = sql.SQL("SELECT ST_GeomFromText({})").format(sql.Literal(polygon_text)) then query = sql.SQL("SELECT ST_Intersects({}, {})").format(geometry, other_geometry) this example is using python but you can just run these sql statements from a prompt too. Make sense? other_geometry is polygons from the other table you THINK should match. You can also make some very simple polygons to test with.

Comment: Also use https://geojson.io and goto their "open" menu and select a file containing all your MULTIPOLYGON points. It will draw it for u!

Comment: Also use https://geojson.io and goto their "open" menu and select a file containing all your MULTIPOLYGON points. It will draw it for u!